# Chrome loading cached Javascript despite clearing cache, delete/reinstall, new MAMP host setup, etc

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, developer-tools

I have tried numerous items to clear the Javascript cache for a Sencha Touch 2 app I am developing using MAMP on my Mac. I have deleted the Chrome cache, disabled/enabled and toggled 'Disable Cache' in Developer Tools numerous times. I have also tried setting up a new host in MAMP Pro to try and force a refresh as a different domain.

Chrome refuses to clear the cache and is consistently showing old cached version of Javascript.

I have also tried the following in my `app.js` for Sencha Touch 2 cache disable.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  disableCaching: false
});
```

I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop Chrome Caching My JS Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392441/stop-chrome-caching-my-js-files)

Answer (score 0):

Trying using a timestamp... `app.js?102390903452`

If that doesn't work... there's something fishy going on, except the cache.

Make this steps

- check the javascript path.
- if you're developing on a remove server, check the connection; in any case, reconnect;
- remove the file completly( make backup of course)
- access javascript directly domain/files/js.js see what you get

Comment: How do I do this? I see that google chrome automatically appends a timestamp to the file like you mentioned and with each refresh it does change, however the old version of code still shows.

Comment: I am using MAMP Pro to develop on my local Macbook Pro. I have tried changing the path for this host to `/` root and Chrome still loads the cached Javascript. Accessing the Javascript file directly does show the changes made since the cached copy that Chrome displays.

Comment: Then i'm out of ideas... it's odd indeed, but these things sometimes happen. You should continue your development on another browser (if you don't code something specifically for chrome), until someone comes with a better solution...

Comment: It is happening on Safari as well so I'm guessing that this is an issue with Webkit engine.