# How do you clear the google cache when creating a google hangout app via the hangout api

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm playing with the google+ api, and when I create my app, I can't modify the app (when viewing it a 2nd time) without actually changing the name of my primary javascript file and xml file.  I've cleared my browser cache and the server cache where I host my xml file  ...... how do I clear the cache at google.

Answer (score 2):

As I just solved a similar problem after too many hours, so here's what worked for me:

My guess is your browser is caching your JS files. In Chrome's developer Tools, you can disable JS caching while Dev. Tools is open. Open your Developer Tools (F12), and click on the settings wheel in the bottom, right corner. Check "**Disable cache (while DevTools is open)**".

My answer is the same as this thread: [Stop Chrome Caching My JS Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392441/stop-chrome-caching-my-js-files)