# Angular js browser issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm working in angular js project, when i change any line of code in a **js** file i should go back to the browser and clear the cache  and the  navigation data.
i'm wondering if there is a solution to force the browser to take my js changes without clearing the cache every time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like to use Cache Killer as a chrome extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Chrome Caching My JS Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392441/stop-chrome-caching-my-js-files)

Comment: Thank you  @element11 for your response , what about if the project in production mode, should i told my users to install Cache Killer in their browsers?

Comment: @Ali I wouldnt tell users to do download anything like that ever. I just use it for development. If you need to inform users machines to redownload files, i know you can use `?version` param when loading javascript files, and you might want to look into the meta solutions suggested. Haven't had too much experience with it. Good luck.

Comment: @element11 thank you  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add those meta tags in your page

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
```

You can also achieve this on server-side, assuming res is your response object

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
res.header('Expires', '-1');
res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
```

Checkout [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) from Google to learn more about HTTP Caching

Comment: better answer ! if any source is provided to study more would  be helpful

Comment: @Angular_10 Checkout [this article](http://odino.org/rest-better-http-cache/) or [this one](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to achieve this is to open Chrome Development Tools and check **Disable cache** option under **Network** tab.

Comment: Hi @stej4, i'm looking for a programmatically solution , because i can't told users to do this, if the project in the production mode..

Answer (score 0):

For your development process, you might use an extension like [Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap) as suggested by @element11.

In production, you can use the [HTML5 Application Cache](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) to specify the files that should get cached.
If you include a version comment in the cache manifest file, you can update this version comment with each release, and the clients will refresh their cache.

Additionally, you might want to take a look at [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).