# Automatic Clearing Cached in Google Chrome (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, browser-cache

Currently, I am working on ASP.net application, just a simple Application called LRS or Leave Request System. So here is a brief summary of my problem. After changing some of my code in the javascript file and Try to Debug and Re-build it, the code I've edited or added is not working, basically, in a stand-alone system, if you change some of its code and debug it, the code you have edited will be triggered.

for example in WinForms application.

```
Private Sub CBCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles CBCancel.Click
   #if 1 then 'New Command
    m_bCancelFlg = False
    Me.Hide()
   #else 'Old
    m_bCancelFlg = True
    Me.Hide()
   #end if
End Sub
```

In this case, the code you have change will be triggered as soon as you click the button.

But in Javascript Function, if you change some of its lines. The new code will not be triggered unless you Clear the Cached of Chrome.

So my question is, Is it possible to clear the previous cached of my application after you visit it again after leaving?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Chrome Caching My JS Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392441/stop-chrome-caching-my-js-files)

Comment: Caching is not that easy, especially in chrome. A common solution is, to add a timestamp query param to your ressource files (e.g. myscript.js?t=20181005080432).

Comment: @DavidSdot Maybe this example solution help others. but my question is removing of cached in chrome using javascript, not disabling it in the web.