# My javascript files functions not working

Tags: javascript

I am new to web develeopment. When I bring changes to my javascript code it does not apear on refresh.

I have included my js file in the head tag.

```
function changecolor() {
    this.styles.color = "gray"
}
```

It still show an alert when i click my button.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The example you posted is not sufficient for us to reproduce the problem. We need to know what is calling `changeColor()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using chrome hold shift and click reload or f5. This will erase the cache and reload the file.

Comment: It worked. Can I disable the caching in chrome. Can you help me please?

Comment: This should really be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @WaisKamal why?

Comment: Read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) documentation.

Comment: @WaisKamal thnx. I didnt know that. What should I do? Should I delete my answer? And paste it in comment section?

Comment: @Ali Qadir please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392441/stop-chrome-caching-my-js-files

Comment: @AliBabaAzimi nevermind, as it solved the OP's problem and it is now accepted :)